# Where can I find official documentation on reading OutputDebugString() messages?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing my own version of DebugView using this article:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23776/Mechanism-of-OutputDebugString
as a starting point.
According to the article `OutputDebugString()` first locks a mutex named `"DBWinMutex"` and the writes to a 4096 bytes area of shared memory named `"DBWIN_BUFFER"` and then signals an event named `"DBWIN_DATA_READY"`.
The code seems to be working fine. However how can I make sure that it will work for all versions of Window?
What prevents Microsoft from e.g. renaming the shared memory area to `"DBWIN_BUFFER2"`?

I am looking for some offical documentation of the DBWIN mechanism and ideally also a header file with defines of these string constants.

Comment: Of course, nothing prevents Microsoft from renaming it... except major headaches for them. They'd have to spend time retooling some of their stuff public and internal, and for what? If it works on Windows 7 and the latest Windows 10, then you can say that it's been stable for 12 years? Probably not going to change.

Comment: There are a number of DebugView alternatives on github which you can draw some inspiration from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is asking about implementation details, that are deliberately not publicly documented. The documented way to receive data from a call to `OutputDebugString` is to call [WaitForDebugEventEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugeventex) and evaluate `OUTPUT_DEBUG_STRING_INFO` [DEBUG_EVENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minwinbase/ns-minwinbase-debug_event)s.

The documentation comes with a full sample on how to [write the debugger's main loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/writing-the-debugger-s-main-loop).

Comment: "*The documented way is...*" - which only works inside of the process that is the active debugger attached to the process that is calling `OutputDebugString()`. The thing about DebugView is that it is not a debugger, hence why it needs to dig a little deeper into the implementation to get the messages